# Rewriting URL on Wordpress for custom content

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an issue rewriting a url properly. We use a product slider plugin which also includes a single product view. The view has the url

> product/?single_prod_id={id}

which is not every elegant. I managed to rewrite it succesfully to work as

> product/{id}/

That's still not good enough though. I would like to have it work as

> product/{id}/{productname}/

With the productname not being important. It's just so the url would look more sensible.

I tried to do

> RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/$    product/?single_prod_id=$1&none=$2 [L]

but on Wordpress that then lead to an page not found error. I experimented with just putting a static string in there, but that also lead to an error. As you can see I am not very experienced with rewriting urls and hope that you can give me some idea where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ product?single_prod_id=$1&none=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This sadly just outputs a 404.